# Log-likelihood fuction beta rectangular distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning

> Let
>   $$b(y|\mu,\phi)=\frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(\mu\phi)\Gamma((1-\mu)\phi)}y^{\mu\phi-1}(1-y)^{(1-u)\phi-1}$$
>   where $0<\mu<1$ and $\phi>0$ a reparametrization of beta distribution.
>   Then the density of beta rectangular is
>   $$f(y|\mu,\phi,\theta)=\theta+(1-\theta)b(y|\mu,\phi)$$ where
>   $0\leq\theta\leq 1$ is a mixture parameter.

I need to find the log-likelihood function of $f(.)$ then I did
$$log(f(y|\mu,\phi,\theta)=log\theta+log(1-\theta)+log(\Gamma(\phi))-log(\Gamma(\mu\phi))-log(\Gamma((1-\mu)\phi))+(\mu\phi-1)log(y)+((1-\mu)\phi-1)log(1-y)$$

Is this log-likelihood correct? I am doing some calculations that are based on it and comparing with the results of the conventional beta, but the results are not as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint likelihood of the parameters, given a sample $\boldsymbol y$ from the distribution with density $f$ is $$\mathcal L(\mu, \phi, \theta \mid \boldsymbol y) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \theta + (1-\theta) b(y_i \mid \mu, \phi) \right).$$  Thus the log-likelihood is $$\ell(\mu, \phi, \theta \mid \boldsymbol y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log \left(\theta + (1-\theta) b(y_i \mid \mu, \phi) \right).$$  The error you are making is that $$\log (x + y) \ne \log x + \log y.$$  This is one reason why mixture distributions are not easy to work with.

Comment: Can you give me any more help? I'm stuck

Comment: Unless there are any additional assumptions you wish to make regarding the model, or you specify additional details about what you are seeking to do, what I have written in my response above is just about the best you can do.

Comment: I tested in the software that I'm using and worked. I have tried for several hours to divide the likelihood into terms, rather than simply having written in the form you presented.